# need to reorder list of objects based on index in angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my angularjs application, I have the following list of objects.

```
$scope.itemsList = [
  {  
    "setupId": "T_2893",   
    "name" : "abc"

  },
  {   
    "setupId": "LBT826",   
    "name" : "xyz"

  },
  {   
    "setupId": "LBT1252",
   "name" : "pqr"

  },
  {   
    "setupId": "G1252",
   "name" : "dwr"

  }
]
```

Now when I call $scope.changeOreder(1, 3) function it should reorder the objects based on the prev and next index. so the list should be as follows.

```
  $scope.itemsList = [
      {  
        "setupId": "T_2893",   
        "name" : "abc"

      },      
      {   
        "setupId": "LBT1252",
       "name" : "pqr"

      },
      {   
        "setupId": "G1252",
       "name" : "dwr"

      },
       {   
        "setupId": "LBT826",   
        "name" : "xyz"

      }
    ]
```

Now if I call, `$scope.changeOreder(2, 0)`, the new list should be,

```
$scope.itemsList = [
          {   
            "setupId": "G1252",
           "name" : "dwr"

          },
          {  
            "setupId": "T_2893",   
            "name" : "abc"

          },      
          {   
            "setupId": "LBT1252",
           "name" : "pqr"

          },          
           {   
            "setupId": "LBT826",   
            "name" : "xyz"

          }
        ]
```

In my $scope.changeOrder function, I have tried different ways, like taking the back up of the object at `prevIndex` , then deleting the obj at `prevIndex` to insert the backed up  obj at `newIndex`, but because I have deleted the object the `newIndex` is no more valid in the current list!!!. Like this I tried different different ways but the final list is not getting ordered the way I am expecting. Can any one help me in fixing it.

Comment: Why not create a new array with the objects that is re-ordered and then just make the old array equal to the new one once you're done?

Answer (score 2):

Moving an item to a specified index:

```
var items = [
          {   
            "setupId": "G1252",
           "name" : "dwr"

          },
          {  
            "setupId": "T_2893",   
            "name" : "abc"

          },      
          {   
            "setupId": "LBT1252",
           "name" : "pqr"

          },          
           {   
            "setupId": "LBT826",   
            "name" : "xyz"

          }
        ];


function moveItem(posA, posB) {
  /*
  * If an item is moved from a higher index to a lower index, then we need to
  * remove the current item first, then add it.
  * When moving a item from a low index to a higer index, then we need to add
  * the item first, then delete it.
  */
  var upToDown = posA > posB;


  var itemToMove = items[posA];
  //Make copy first
  var tmpList = items.slice(0); 

  if (!upToDown) {
      //Add item to specified index
    tmpList.splice(posB+1, 0, itemToMove); 

    //Remove the old item
    tmpList.splice(posA, 1); 
  } else { 
    //Remove the old item
    tmpList.splice(posA, 1); 
      //Add item to specified index
    tmpList.splice(posB, 0, itemToMove);

  }
  return tmpList;
} 

var result = moveItem(0, 3); 
console.log(result);
```

Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/23DGzcXBEY7qrqFWsQNA?p=preview

Comment: If you want to modify an existing array by adding/deleting elements, then I recommend to make use of  ````angular.copy()```` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: This is a very simple solution to swap items. The problem in the posted question was that items were deleted, which is unnecessary if only their content changes.

Comment: com2ghz, there is a bug in your solution, it exchanges the two positions objects but that is not I want. I want one object to be dragged to either left or right and adjust remaining objects positions accordingly.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check if this is what you want.